# Как восстановить цвет объекта при повторном нажатии (если при первом нажатии цвет изменяется и при этом объектов больше одного)?

Tags: unity3d

Проблема в повторном нажатии с учётом, что объект не один (а значит и цвета у них разные), как сохранить и восстановить цвета объектов. К примеру две коробки: желтая и синяя, мы изменяем цвет обоих на черный, как восстановить их первоначальный цвет?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class VisualRay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.UI.Selectable CurrentSelectable;
    private Color color;
    void LateUpdate()
    {   
        Ray ray =  Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward*100f, Color.yellow);
        
        
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {       

            GameObject selectable = hit.collider.gameObject;
            if ((selectable.tag == "Box") && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)))
            {
                color = selectable.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
                selectable.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
            }
               
        }
    }
}
```

Пробовал вот так, но не получилось:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class VisualRay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Pointer;
    public UnityEngine.UI.Selectable CurrentSelectable;
    private Color color;
    bool Transform_color = false;
    void LateUpdate()
    {   
        Ray ray =  Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward*100f, Color.yellow);
        
        
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            Pointer.position = hit.point;

            GameObject selectable = hit.collider.gameObject;
            if ((selectable.tag == "Box") && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)))
            {
                if (Transform_color == false)
                {
                    color = selectable.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
                    selectable.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
                    Transform_color = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    selectable.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = color;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем проблема? Если вы умеете ставить цвет на красный при нажатии F, то в чем проблема поставить цвет на начальный (можно сохранить в переменную) при нажатии другой кнопки, или отжатии F, или любого другого события?

Comment: Изменил вопрос.

Comment: То есть вам нужно, чтобы при нажатии на коробку цвет менялся на черный, при повторном нажатии — на начальный? При этом коробки друг от друга не зависят?

Comment: Да, сори, что долго не отвечал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнём с того необходимо создать скрипт для коробки, к примеру `Box.cs`

в `Box.cs` создать поле с ссылкой на `Renderer` для смены цвета по `material.color`, и два поля с `Color`, одно под цвет выделения другое под "базовый цвет".

Пример:

```cs
private Renderer _renderer;

[Serialize Field] private Color _highlightColor = Color.green;
[Serialize Field] private Color _defaultColor;

public Color highlightColor { get => _highlightColor ; set => _highlightColor = value; }

private void Awake()
{
   _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
}

public void SwitchColor(bool isSelected)
{
   isSelected == true ? _renderer.material.color = _highlightColor : _renderer.material.color = _defaultColor; // Тернарный оператор
}
```

И создать метод который меняет цвет в зависимости от своего параметра.

Обратите внимание чтобы данный скрипт был на обьекте с `Renderer` либо укажите путь до него самостоятельно.

И теперь вам остаётся только обратится к данному методу:

```cs
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {       
    
                GameObject selectable = hit.collider.gameObject;

                if ((selectable.GetComponent<Box>()) && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)))
                {
                    color = selectable.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
                    selectable.GetComponent<Box>().highlightColor = color;
                    selectable.GetComponent<Box>().SwitchColor(true);
                }
                   
            }
```

Comment: А зачем делать `[SerializeField] private _highlightColor` и приватное свойство `highlightColor`, если можно просто сделать публичное поле `highlightColor`. Так как оно публично, то к нему можно будет обратиться из инспектора и из других скриптов, если нужно. К тому же в свойстве нет никаких функций: просто установка и чтение. Есть причина?